# How do we pass the value to all the elements of GUI in this QT code

Tags: c++, qt

I'm reading a book on QT4 and here's an example from the book:

> ```
> QApplication a(argc, argv); 
> QWidget window;
>
> QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(&window);
>
> QLabel* label = new QLabel("0");
> QSpinBox* spinBox = new QSpinBox;
> QSlider* slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
>
> mainLayout->addWidget(label);
> mainLayout->addWidget(spinBox);
> mainLayout->addWidget(slider);
>
> QObject::connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), label, SLOT(setNum(int)));
> QObject::connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
> QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), label, SLOT(setNum(int)));
> QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spinBox, SLOT(setValue(int)));
>
> window.show();
> ```

As the book and compilation show, changing the value of one of the widgets leads to changing the values of the other elements.

What **I don't understand** is how it happens. How do we pass that value from one widget to the rest? There's no variable that gets changed by means of one widget and gets passed to the others.

PS Conceptually, I do understand the idea of slots and signals and 'connect'. It's how the value is passed from one widget to the rest is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signal is a C++ method with code generated by a utility called `moc` (meta object compiler). A slot is regular C++ method, with code under your control. A connection is a way of letting the signal know what slots to call. When the signal gets emitted, it really means that you call the machine-generated method that iterates the connection list.

Conceptually, the `valueChanged` signal implementation looks like this:

```
void valueChanged(int value) {
  for (slot : this->slots)
    (slot.object->*slot.method)(value);
}
```

Thus, when the slider "emits" its signal, it calls each slot with a given value. After the connections are made, you should think of the spinbox's `valueChanged` signal as doing the following:

```
void SpinBox::valueChanged(int value) {
  // 1st connection
  label->setNum(value);
  // 2nd connection
  slider->setVale(value);
}
```

There's no "variable" that gets changed because the signal-slot mechanism is, at its core, an easier-to-use way of doing indirect method calls (via method pointers and instance pointers).

In modern code (Qt5/C++11), that example would be (this is complete code):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   QApplication a{argc, argv};
   QWidget window;

   QVBoxLayout mainLayout{&window};

   QLabel label{"0"};
   QSpinBox spinBox;
   QSlider slider{Qt::Horizontal};

   mainLayout.addWidget(&label);
   mainLayout.addWidget(&spinBox);
   mainLayout.addWidget(&slider);

   QObject::connect(&spinBox, static_cast<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
                    &label, static_cast<void(QLabel::*)(int)>(&QLabel::setNum));
   QObject::connect(&spinBox, static_cast<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
                    &slider, static_cast<void(QSlider::*)(int)>(&QSlider::setValue));
   QObject::connect(&slider, static_cast<void(QSlider::*)(int)>(&QSlider::valueChanged),
                    &label, static_cast<void(QLabel::*)(int)>(&QLabel::setNum));
   QObject::connect(&slider, &QSlider::valueChanged, &spinBox, &QSpinBox::setValue);

   window.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```